# Change the text size of Bokeh label annotations

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm adding label annotations to Bokeh bar chart :

```
labels = LabelSet(x='roomsavailable', y='area', text='roomsavailable', level='glyph',
        x_offset=-15, y_offset=-13.5, source=source, render_mode='canvas')

p.add_layout(labels)
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to adjust the size of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In the docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.LabelSet) it describes the `text_font_size` attribute:

> The text font size values for the text.

So try something like

```
YOUR_FONT_SIZE = 10
labels = LabelSet(x='stock',
                  y='area',
                  text='roomsavailable',
                  text_font_size=YOUR_FONT_SIZE,
                  level='glyph',
                  x_offset=-15,
                  y_offset=-13.5,
                  source=source,
                  render_mode='canvas')
```

Comment: This doesn't work as is. You need to input YOUR_FONT_SIZE variable as a string and with units, like '10pt', like the answer from @Johnathan Huggett.

Answer (score 5):

text_font_size takes in a string value like 
YOUR_FONT_SIZE = '10pt'

Answer (score 4):

You can also add the following code:

```
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '15pt'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '15pt'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an extantion to the already existing answer by @MarkWeston.

Let's take a look to this minimal example below:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[x for x in range(1,8)], 
                               y=[1]*7, 
                               names=[str(x) for x in range(1,8)]
                              )
                         )

p = figure(x_range=(0, 8), y_range=(0, 2), plot_height=100, tools='' )

labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='names', level='overlay', text_align='center',
              x_offset=0, y_offset=-8, source=source, render_mode='canvas')
p.add_layout(labels)

p.circle(x='x', y='y', radius=0.3, alpha=0.3, source=source)

p.xgrid.visible = False
p.ygrid.visible = False
p.xaxis.visible = False
p.yaxis.visible = False

show(p)
```

This is the output of the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5iu6.png).

Now we can follow the answer by @MarkWeston and set the parameter we want beforehand.
If you create a `LabelSet` you can pass all parameters explained in the [documentation of LabelSet](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#bokeh.models.annotations.LabelSet).

But there is also a second way, if you want to change your settings after calling `p.add_layout()`.

The function `p.add_layout(labels)` comes with a parameter called `place`. Valid values are `left`, `right`, `above`, `below` and the default value `center`. For more see also the [documentation to add_layout](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/map_plots.html?highlight=add_layout#bokeh.models.map_plots.GMapPlot.add_layout).

For simplification let's assume that you call the `add_layout()` function with the default value `center`. Now we need to now, at which index of the list contained in `p.center` our `LabelSet` is placed.

We can get this information by running

```
[i for i, item in enumerate(p.center) if isinstance(item, LabelSet)]
>>> [2]
```

which will return "[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u94M4.png)". Note that at 0 and 1 there are the invisible grids.

Now we can change our parameter settings of this `LabelSet` calling lines like

```
p.center[2].text_color = {'value':'#0000ff'}
p.center[2].text_size = {'value':'11pt'}
p.center[2].text_size = 'TimesNewRoman'
```

and many more.

If you plot the figure again with `show(p)` you can see the changes and it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u94M4.png).